# "I've known her very well" vs. "I know her very well"

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple

> Jane and I are friends. (I know / I've known) her very well.

The answer is 'I know'. I want to know why 'I've known' cannot be the answer in this short question.

Comment: Both tenses are perfectly fine. It's not the case that *I've known* cannot be the answer. It depends on what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the verb "know" makes "I've known her well" unlikely.

The verb "know" describes a state, so it isn't necessary to use the present perfect to mean "a state continuing to the present". Using the present perfect would suggest that you are using "know" to describe an action at some point in the past.  In English "know" does not mean "the action of learning about something".

So "I know her well" is the only correct answer.

Comment: If you wanted to talk about the action of learning about her, then perfect tense expressions like "I've got to know her very well" (UK) or "I've gotten to know her very well" (US) would work.

Answer (score -1):

"Jane and I **are** friends" implies **present** tense.

"I **know** her very well" is also **present** tense, while "**I've** known her very well" implies **present perfect** tense. The correct grammar matches both tenses of the two sentences. Therefore, "I've known her very well" is incorrect.

If you wish to use "I've known her very well", then I believe "Jane and I have been friends. I've known her very well" is grammatically correct.

To further clarify, the conjugation "I've" can be broken down into "I **have**", which implies **present perfect** tense, or ownership.

Present perfect Tense: "I have [verb]"
This expresses the idea that something occurred at an unspecified time before now or possibly even now. It's similar to saying "I have the experience of..."
For example: "I have walked with her before"

Ownership: "I have [object]"
For example: I have an apple.

I hope this helps! Best of luck with learning!

Reference: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html

EDIT: Replaced "past tense" with "present perfect tense". Explained a bit more what present perfect tense is.